# Variational calculus and KKR method for band structure calculation

Tags: solid-state-physics, variational-principle, electronic-band-theory, variational-calculus

I’ve been studying the KKR method from the original Kohn and Kostoker’s paper (https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.94.1111).
On the text, they use variational calculus for dealing with an integral equation. Namely, the paper states that the integral equation (2.14):

$\psi(\vec{r})=\int G(\vec{r},\vec{r}_0)V(\vec{r}_0)\psi(\vec{r}_0)d^3r_0$

Is equivalent to:

$\delta\Lambda=0$

Where:

$\Lambda=\int \psi^*(\vec{r})V(\vec{r})\psi(\vec{r})d^3r-\int  \psi^*(\vec{r})V(\vec{r})G(\vec{r},\vec{r}_0)V(\vec{r}_0)\psi(\vec{r}_0)d^3rd^3r_0$

However, my understanding of variational techniques is that you are supposed to minimize (or extremize) an action integral of a lagrangean. And that the result turns out to be that the integral path for which the action is an extreme is a solution to an Euler-Lagrange equation.

But I’m not able to see how this applies to an integral equation like this, or how the expression for $\Lambda$ appears. The fact that the authors proceed to extremize $\Lambda$ cofuses me even more, since some textbooks call this function the “lagrangean”.

How does the variational method applies on situations like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, my understanding of variational techniques is that you are supposed to minimize (or extremize) an action integral of a lagrangean.

You can minimize whatever you want.

See, for example, Chapter 17 (Calculus of Variations) of *Mathematical Methods For Physicists* (4th Edition) by Arfken and Weber. In particular section 17.1 where is it proved that the integral:
$$
J=\int f(y,y;x)dx
$$
is stationary for:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} = 0\;.
$$

No mention of Lagrangians whatsoever in that entire Section!

> How does the variational method applies on situations like this?

It applies because making the integral stationary results in the desired differential equation, in particular, since there's no $\psi'$ term, and since we can treat $\psi$ and $\psi^*$ independently:
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial \psi(x)}
\left(
\int\psi^*V\psi-\int\int\psi*VGV\psi
\right)=0
\to
$$
$$
\psi^*(x)V(x)-\int \psi^*(r)V(r)G(r,x)V(x)=0
\to
$$
$$
\psi(\vec x)=\int d^3r \psi(\vec r)V^*(\vec r)G^*(r,x)=0
$$

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer! May I ask you how this derivative is made? I mean, how the derivative of the wave function eliminates the integral, which is on the space coordinates?

Comment: It's a variational derivative, I used the symbol $\partial$, but it should be understood it's a variational derivative in the calculus or variations sense... I can explain more later, but not at the moment.